# Flow rates correlations or Flow rate correlations

Tags: grammatical-number

I do have a rather basic question. Does one say:
"Flow rates correlations" or "Flow rate correlations" in English.
Is there some specific rule to follow here?

Comment: That aside, one needs to say English with a capital 'E' and every sentence must begin with a capital. Questions end with an appropriate 'question mark.'

Comment: Hi, I do have a rather basic question. In English, does one say: "Flow rates correlations" or "Flow rate correlations"? Is there some specific rule to follow here? thanks in advance for your valuable help.

Comment: "Flow rate correlations" no need to pluralize the adjective phrase. HTH.

Comment: Kris, thanks for the prompt relpy and clarification.